# Inverse Function of $(1-e^{-t})t$

Tags: special-functions

I'm interested if there is some hope to obtain the inverse of
$$ f(t) = (1-e^{-t})t $$
for $t$ positive. If there is a formula I suspect that the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) will be involved on it. Clever approximations are also welcomed (not looking for local ones though ;).

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) could be applicable. If the derivatives become manageable is as yet to be found.

Comment: There certainly won't be any way to do it using just the ordinary functions of high school math.

Comment: Maple doesn't find the inverse in terms of the W function; it usually succeeds to find such in cases where there is an inverse involving W.

Comment: It is strictly increasing, so it must have an inverse.

Comment: @Bunder Sorry, brain fart.

Comment: Near $t=0$ this is $f(t) \approx t^2$ so it is not increasing or invertible.

Comment: To define the inverse, the function needs to be single valued, so you would have to restrict the domain of $t$ to be either $t\ge0$ or $t\le0$. The domain of the inverse function $t(f)$ is then the range of $f(t)$ which in either case is $f\ge0$.

Comment: @Maesumi and Graham it is for $t$ positive so the inverse is well defined.

Comment: Ha ha woops didn't read the question properly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large $t$ $f(t)\sim t$, while for small t $f(t)\sim t^2$. Then for large $y$ $f^{-1}(y)\sim y$ and for small $y$ $f^{-1}(y)\sim \sqrt y$. Using this as a first approximation in Newton's method gives the following approximation:
$$
f^{-1}(y)\sim h(y)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{y}-\frac{-y-e^{-\sqrt{y}} \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{y}}{e^{-\sqrt{y}}
   \sqrt{y}-e^{-\sqrt{y}}+1}& 0<y<1,\\
y+\frac{e^{-y} y}{e^{-y} y-e^{-y}+1}& y\ge1.
\end{cases}
$$
This is the graph of $f^{-1}(y)-h(y)$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you comment on how exactly you used Newton's method?

Comment: Given $y>0$, let $g(t)=f(t)-y$. Newton's method to solve $g(t)=0$ consists in iterating the function $N(t)=t-g(t)/g'(t)$ starting with an initial guess $t_0$. If $y<1$ take as initial guess $t_0=\sqrt y$; if $y\ge1$ take $t_0=y$.

Comment: Thanks again! . I'll give your idea a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maple does give us a series for it:  if $(1-e^{-t})t = y$ and $t>0$, then
$$
t = {y}^{1/2}+\frac{1}{4}\,y+{\frac {7}{96}}\,{y}^{3/2}+1/48\,{y}^{2}+{\frac {491}
{92160}}\,{y}^{5/2}+{\frac {1}{960}}\,{y}^{3}+{\frac {983}{20643840}}
\,{y}^{7/2}-{\frac {11}{120960}}\,{y}^{4}-{\frac {2455961}{39636172800
}}\,{y}^{9/2}-{\frac {79}{2903040}}\,{y}^{5}-{\frac {1131731179}{
125567395430400}}\,{y}^{11/2}+\dots 
$$